# Why is this prune being done by my program?

Tags: algorithm, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I created program which does alpha beta algorithm on a graph.

(Images are clickable for a larger version)

I have this graph:

[image: my graph]

Result of the algorithm:

[image: result]

This image shows the problem area:

[image]

Why were these two nodes pruned? First node of group is 5, parent node of previous vertexes is 2, so we compare 5 and 2. **5 is not less than 2**, but the program made the cut-off. Why? It must do it only if node value is lesser then 2, but it is not in our case.

Am I misunderstanding something in alpha-beta pruning theory, so I am comparing the wrong values? Or is it a problem of my realization? All other branches before worked perfectly, so why does the problem only appear here? On the other hand, look at this image:

[image]

The program must prune and the prune is done. Why is it pruning when the first child vertex is either 5 or 1?

---

My alpha beta function ([on GitHub](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/minimax/blob/Working/tree.js#L13-L40)):

```
function alphabeta_blank(node, depth, alpha, beta, isMax, g) {
    g.nodes[node.name].shape.items['0'].attr('fill', 'green');

    if((depth == 0) || (node.isTerminal == true)) {
        return node.value;
    }
    if(isMax) {
        for (var i in node.children) {
            var child = node.children[i];
            alpha = Math.max(alpha, alphabeta_blank(child, depth-1, alpha, beta, false, g));
            if(beta <= alpha) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return alpha;
    } else {
        for (var i in node.children) {
            var child = node.children[i];
            beta = Math.min(beta, alphabeta_blank(child, depth-1, alpha, beta, true, g));
            if (beta <= alpha) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return beta;
    }
}
```

This function is a translation of [the pseudocode on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning#Pseudocode) to JavaScript.

Note: if you open the full source, you will notice that I showed the `alpha_beta_blank` function here - this function is a translation of the Wikipedia pseudocode. Actually, I am using another function in my program, but **neither** are working correctly, as described above.

About debugging. You can look at [this function](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/minimax/blob/Working/tree.js#L42-L114) (original function with all debugging statements) and see that I am printing debug messages. This part from debug trace belongs to the problem vertexes:

```
minimizing (min312)
getting value from terminal node node31 (value is 5)
beta value is set to 5
alpha cut-off (5<=5), others children of max31 wouldn't be visited
min312 — minimum of childs of min312 is 5
min312 — childs of node min312: [5]
returning beta, minimal node is 5, node min312 value is set as 5
going back to node max31
```

Part of graph with names (so you can understand the logs):

```
             max31
            /       \
      min311         min312
     ........     /    |     \
                 /     |      \
child:          5      4       5
```

[Full repository on GitHub](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/minimax/tree/Working).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By exploring 1st sub-tree (from root) we have found out that we are guaranteed to get the result of 5 so when we go to that "troublesome" node and get the value of 5 we can prune because there's no way the min node would take higher value and of course we don't want to try get even lower value since we can always go to the first sub-tree and get the result of 5 (same applies to your other example when its 1, because 5 is better than 1). Although if it was 6 instead then it wouldn't prune.

The alpha value is not 2 at that place but it's 5 because it get carried over from 1st sub-tree as the guaranteed maximum value. So that's why your written comparison `2<5` is incorrect and should be `5<=5` which is true.

Comment: I understand what you said, but... I was doing same on paper and teacher said, that we should compare this value vs 2 (2 is previous group best value — [this value](http://i.gyazo.com/529b3d3b76975fffbfa9d3406be6cfb3.png)). So he was wrong and I am misunderstanding how alpha-beta-pruning should work? When I am doing same on paper I don't save alpha and beta on each step. He explained, that I just should watch on previous group bestvalue (as I explained earlier). It is wrong?

Comment: Actually, I was thinking about it. There is no video on youtube, which is explaining alpha-beta like he did. Everywhere guys explain, that there are alpha and beta and they changing their values throw algorithm.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav it probably works fine using your teachers method.  It seems like a simpler version of "real" alpha-beta algorithm. However as you seen in your example it doesn't prune as much as "correct" alpha-beta could. And in huge trees the impact could be much severe. So I don't see a point using that one and you could show your teacher another method, maybe he/she will learn something new :P

Comment: Heeeey wait. How it can work fine if it is not correct to use comparation 2 and 5? :(

Comment: @SharikovVladislav Because by comparing with previous best group you kinda ignore already known best overall result. However you would still find the best possible value for root node but as I said before it would take more time to do that. As you can see your "teacher's algorithm" wouldn't prune at that node (which is given in example) but the "correct" alpha-beta algorithm would do that (and as you know it have done it indeed).

Comment: Just think about simple minimax without pruning. It always guaranteed to return best result but it won't do any pruning hence will take very long time to traverse full tree. Then it comes your teacher's alpha-beta algorithm who does SOME pruning but still it will take long time to find best value. Finally the "real" alpha-beta algorithm (which is described in wikipedia) does maximum amount of possible pruning.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav if you gonna talk about this with your teacher let me know what's the outcome :)

Comment: Well :) I showed my programm today. Firstly, he was hurry, so he checked only left half of prunes. Also, it was possibility to get "free" mark today, if my programm is ok, so I decided to don't waste more time and just get my profit :)